# не могу добавить COUNT к запросу SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, count

```
create table T1(id int, F1 varchar(100));
insert into T1 values(1, '10,56,657,34,767,71');
insert into T1 values(3, '1,5487,27,9');
insert into T1 values(2, '12,6,65,8,67,22,70,5');
```

Получившаяся таблица

```
id  F1
1   '10,56,657,34,767,71'
3   '1,5487,27,9'
2   '12,6,65,8,67,22,70,5'
```

Задача реализовать запрос для таблицы выше в такой вид

```
id num val
1   1   10
1   2   56
   ...
```

- id – идентификатор
- num - порядковый номер значения в исходной
  строке
- val - значение

Тоесть нужно засплитить значения в первой таблице и сделать запрос при условии что:

- Нужно использовать рекурсивный SQL и конструкцию with.
- Не использовать функции regexp_split_to_table, unnest или подобные.

Мой конечный запрос считает количество всех расспличенных элементов но посчитать нужно количество элементов соответствующих каждому айди.

```
WITH A AS 
        (
         SELECT id , 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f1, ',')) as 'num', 
         value AS 'val'
         FROM T1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f1, ',')
        )
SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY id;
```

Что получается при выполнении приложу в скрине. Если кто соображает подскажите пж как мне Count правильно сделать в этой ситуации.
[image: результат моего запроса]

Comment: 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: *Не использовать функции regexp_split_to_table, unnest или подобные.* В MySQL их по-любому использовать не получится - MySQL таких конструкций тупо не знает - это не PostgreSQL. Да и STRING_SPLIT() он тоже не знает, и CROSS APPLY - это не SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Ладно, для меня это было неочевидно, но я сделал. Если у кого-то будет задача с похожими условиями - пользуйтесь.

```
WITH A As 
        (
          SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by id) num, value As 'val' 
          FROM T1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f1, ',') WHERE id = 1 
          UNION All
          SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by id) id, value 
          FROM T1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f1, ',') WHERE id = 2 
          UNION All
          SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by id) id, value  
          FROM T1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f1, ',') WHERE id = 3
        )
SELECT * FROM A ;
```